# install rpy2 on OS X10.8.5

Tags: python, r, macos, pass-through

newbie in Mac, I want to build the passthrough connection between ipython notebook(/or python2.7) and R.

1. Installed Xcode today, latest version
2. in terminal: pip install rpy2   (then i seee the following error message return)
3. %load_ext rmagic (...)

does anyone meet the similar error message before? if you could share your methods how to solve it that would be great !! Thanks in Advance !!

```
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:51:10: fatal error: 'signal.h' file not found

include <signal.h>
 1 error generated.
  error: command '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
  XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

 Cleaning up...
 Command /Users/AliceXiong/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
 __file__='/private/var/folders/f_/0whwct214sj4nzd0d7rv90p80000gn/
 T/pip_build_AliceXiong/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)     
 (__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record  
 /var/folders/f_/0whwct214sj4nzd0d7rv90p80000gn/T/pip-2lFYqK-record/install-record.txt -- 
 single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in 
 /private/var/folders/f_/0whwct214sj4nzd0d7rv90p80000gn/T/pip_build_AliceXiong/rpy2

 Storing debug log for failure in /Users/AliceXiong/.pip/pip.log
```

actually, I open this debug log (vi .pip.log), but it is an empty file

Comment: @BondedDust Here it seems that R 3.0 is listed:http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/overview.html#requirements

Comment: @lgautier My R version is 3.1.0. And additionally, i just realize that i forget to paste another error message it returns `'signal.h file not found'`. Any idea about how to add in that `signal.h`? Thanks,

Comment: @AliceXiong did you try without anaconda ? `pip install rpy2`

Comment: @BondedDust on this side of the internet rpy2's homepage appears to correctly point to the last version. Regarding R versions, the latest rpy2 is working with the latest R. The doc refers to what was the target R during development.

Comment: Thank you for correcting. I'll delete my misleading comments.

Comment: @BondedDust  I found that rpy2 is already installed on SageMath, I can play with it from there. Anyhow, rpy2 still have these unfixed bugs on Mac.Since it works well on Linux.